# Where to put javascript function in wordpress to apply to side navigation

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code to initially hide sub navigation of a sidebar menu in wordpress:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".children").hide();
    $("#menu-item").click(function() {
        $('.children').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

I have it working correctly in jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/MLUb8/), but can't get it working in wordpress. Where should it be placed within my theme for this to work? I've tried the header.php, footer.php and template file.

Comment: Make sure you are including jQuery first.  Either in `header.php` or (preferably) both jQuery and your custom script should be added the proper way via `wp_enqueue_script()` in your `functions.php` file.  Note that WP enqueues jQuery by default so you may need to deregister it first if you need to use a different version.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the code in a separate file and include it using `wp_enqueue_script` (the value for `$deps` should be `array( 'jquery' )`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Additionally, WordPress uses noconflict, so you should slightly modify your code, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".children").hide();
    $("#menu-item").click(function() {
        $('.children').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually worked directly within the template file itself. No need to embed from a separate file.